# Deleting from SQL detailsView

Tags: asp.net

Hey I am just learning to how to use asp.net and I am trying to use the grid view to display information and details view edit/delete the information from the database.  Right now I can edit and update the information in the database but I also want it to delete and something is not working for me.  I set up an exception and when I select the item and press delete it pops up my exception that another user has deleted the item when it hasn't.  Im not really sure what i have done wrong, to me it looks like it should work.

Here is the code for the delete command and parameters from the details view

```
      DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Customers]
     WHERE [CustomerID] = @original_CustomerID
      AND [Name] = @original_Name
       AND [Address] = @original_Address
        AND [City] = @original_City
         AND [State] = @original_State
          AND [ZipCode] = @original_ZipCode
           AND ([Phone] = @original_Phone 
            OR [Phone] IS NULL  AND @original_Phone IS NULL) 
           AND ([Email] = @original_Email 
           OR [Email] IS NULL AND @original_Email IS NULL)" 

<DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Address" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_City" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_State" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_ZipCode" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Phone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Email" Type="String" />
    </DeleteParameters>
```

and here is the delete functions in the cs file

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemDeleted(object sender, DetailsViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception != null)
    {
        lblError.Text = "A database error has occurred.<br /><br />" +
            "Message: " + e.Exception.Message;
        e.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
    else if (e.AffectedRows == 0)
        lblError.Text = "Another user may have deleted that customer."
            + "<br />Please try again.";
    else
        GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void DetailsView1_ItemDeleting(
    object sender, DetailsViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    e.Values["Name"]
        = e.Values["Name"].ToString().Substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have such a huge query for a delete statement?Have a look how it's done in the [MSDN DetailsView example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z482d0y.aspx)

The CustomerID in your SQL table should be **unique** so your delete statement should be as simple as:

```
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Customers] WHERE [CustomerID] = @original_CustomerID"
```

And only one delete parameter:

```
<DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerID" Type="Int32" />
</DeleteParameters>
```

One more thing which is quite important is you need to set `DataKeyNames="CustomerID"` on the DetailsView so that `DetailsView1_ItemDeleted` knows which row to delete. Hope this helps!

Comment: You're welcome, remember to mark as answered by selecting a tick symbol next to the answer that helped you